# getElementsByTagName doesn't seem to be working in java on jboss 6

Tags: java, xml, jboss

We are migrating applications from JBoss 3.0.8 to 6.1.0. one of the application uses org.w3c.dom packages to deal with xml files. I have this xml

```
<root><data><head1>test1</head1></data><data><head2>test2</head2></data><data><head3>test3</head3></data></root>
```

java code:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(new File("test.xml"));
    DOMResult domResult = new DOMResult(doc);
    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList nodelist = root.getElementsByTagName("data");
    System.out.println("nodelist length : "+nodelist.getLength());
    for (int i = 0; i < nodelist.getLength(); i++) {
        Element node = (Element) nodelist.item(i);
        String fullPathName = "result"+i+".xml";
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(fullPathName);

        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "us-ascii");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION,"no");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(fout));
    }
```

this code does split content into multiple files but does not work in jboss 6. seems like getElementsByTagName is not working on jboss 6. it copies whole original content into all the split files.

Result xml in all files

```
<root><data><head1>test1</head1></data><data><head2>test2</head2></data><data><head3>test3</head3></data></root>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Please edit the question and clarify.

Comment: Thanks. i have edited the question with result xml in all 3 split files.

Comment: I'd say that's an error in the `Transformer` implementation handing a `DOMSource`, in that it doesn't process the sub-tree of the given `node`, but the entire tree. Try this potential work-around: Make the `node` a (dangling) root element by calling `root.removeChild(node)`. Don't know if that'll work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Sorry Andreas it did not work.. it removed the node and copied all the other nodes in all the generated files.

Comment: Is `LSSerializer` available on your platform?

Comment: no we don't have LSSerializer on our platform..

Comment: Seems like the transformer uses the owning `Document` of the `Node` given to the `DOMSource`, so you'll need a new `Document`. Try this: `newdoc = db.newDocument(); newnode = newdoc.importNode(node, true); newdoc.appendChild(newnode);` then use `new DOMSource(newdoc)`.

Comment: Thank you Andreas.  I have tried your suggestion now and that worked perfectly. just wondering if code change is the only solution?